# What is a "spatially encoded qubit"?

Tags: quantum-gate, photonics

I am studying the photonic CNOT (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403062v1).

I am not understanding what is a spatially encoded qubit?
How the setup in fig. 1(b) can create this spatially encoded qubit?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "qubit/qudit" is in general just a degree of freedom of a certain dimension.

So, for example, a single photon can have several degrees of freedom. Its polarisation is one that is often considered, but its *position* is another degree of freedom that is often used to encode information. If a photon (or other particle) can be in one of $N$ possible positions, then that provides you an $N$-dimensional degree of freedom. If it can be in one of two possible spatial positions, then it amounts to a qubit.

In the scheme you're referring to, you have a photon which can be in two different polarisation states, and in two different position states. In other words, the photon is the physical substratum for a *two-qubit system*. One qubit is provided by the polarisation, and the other by the position. Something like a polarising beamsplitter (PBS) effectively acts as a CNOT between these two qubits, as it affects the position conditionally on the polarisation.